# Stringsplode the String!

Tags: code-golf, string

The challenge is relatively simple, but will hopefully lead to some wonderfully creative answers. The task is to take a string as an input (via command line, function parameter etc.) and output/return a stringsploded version of it.

A stringsploded version of a string is its first letter followed by its first 2 letters, followed by its first 3 letters,... until you finally output the complete word.

You are guaranteed that the input will consist of printable ASCII characters and that the input will all be on one line (no new line characters).

Here are examples to clarify what stringsplosions are:

```
Input                 Output
==================================================================
"Code"       ---->   "CCoCodCode"
"name"       ---->   "nnanamname"
"harambe"    ---->   "hhaharharaharamharambharambe"
"sp aces?"   ---->   "sspsp sp asp acsp acesp acessp aces?"
"1234"       ---->   "1121231234"
"ss"         ---->   "sss"
```

This is code golf so shortest code wins + up votes for interesting uses of your respective language.

Good luck!

Comment: Will the input only contain letters?

Comment: @MartinEnder The input is a string that could contain anything that a string would normally contain (limited to ASCII I suppose). Is there an ambiguous area that I haven't addressed?

Comment: String challenges should usually specify the valid input characters, because it's not clear whether the input may contain a) non-letters, b) unprintable/control characters, c) null bytes, d) extended ASCII characters, e) Unicode characters beyond code point 256, (... f) combining marks, g) surrogates ...), all of which can arbitrarily complicate the challenge in many languages. And since your test cases only cover letters one might assume that that's your intended input range.

Comment: You should add a test case where the first two characters are the same.

Comment: As someone with a stutter, I'm OOfOffOffeOffenOffendOffendeOffended.

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring  You sir have a beautifully structured stutter; my OCD is pleased.

Comment: Alternate title: `SStStrStriStrinStringStringsStringspStringsplStringsploStringsplodStringsplode`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I would gladly use that.

Comment: May there be extra whitespace? May we return a list of {"C","Co","Cod",...?

Comment: @Adám You need to output/return a single string so you would need to flatten the list. As for the extra whitespace, only trailing whitespace at the end is allowed.

Comment: [Reeelelelaelaelatelatelateelateelatedelated.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61885/42545)

Comment: [Also related, near duplicate.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68901/42545)

Comment: Damn I searched so long looking for possible duplicates.

Comment: Literally no point closing this. 43 answers and literally no one cares that it's a duplicate of an 8 month old post.

Comment: @MartinEnder Since the requirements are more lenient [there](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68901/42545), all solutions here are valid there too. Shouldn't this post's answers posts migrated and this post removed?

Comment: @Adám If that were to happen, there's not doubt that some answers would be duplicates or each other.

Answer (score 20):

## [gs2](http://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 1 byte

## [`x`](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=eA&input=SGVsbG8)

- `gs2` takes input from STDIN, and pushes it to the stack as a string.
- `x` is the **prefixes** built-in, returning a list of all prefixes of the argument, in ascending-length order.
- The resulting list of strings is implicitly printed one-by-one, without a delimiter, when the program terminates.

Comment: Wow Speechless automagic wizardry

Answer (score 13):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
;\
```

Acculumate over concatenation gives all prefixes, which Jelly outputs to STDOUT without a delimiter. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O1w&input=&args=ImFiY2RlMDEyMz8hICMi)

Comment: Oh, cumulative reduce and reduce never seem to do what I expect. Surely a winner! [Test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O1wKw4figqxZ&input=&args=IkNvZGUiLCJuYW1lIiwiaGFyYW1iZSIK)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Uh oh, Lynn did 1 byte :D

Answer (score 8):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 4 bytes

```
.
$`
```

Expects the input to be terminated with a Windows-style `\r\n` newline (which seems fitting for a .NET-based programming language...).

This can be tested on [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.&i=Code+Golf%0d%0a&r=%24%60) (which uses `\r\n` newlines). Click the "Context" tab for the result.

This is essentially the same as [Jordan's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92536/8478): it replaces each character in the input (including the `\r` but not the `\n`) with all the characters that came before it.

Answer (score 8):

### Java 7, <s>81</s> 78 bytes

```
String g(String a){for(int i=a.length();i>0;)a=a.substring(0,--i)+a;return a;}
```

Straightforward method. Repeatedly prepends the shrinking prefix until it's done.

As a bonus, it should work for non-ASCII as well.

Sample:

```
Input:  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
Output: (( ( ͡( ͡°( ͡° ( ͡° ͜( ͡° ͜ʖ( ͡° ͜ʖ ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
```

Comment: You've beat me to it. Also, +1 I like the Lenny Face example.

Comment: Haha, yes. I like to think of it as Lenny sliding into the room [Kramer style](https://youtu.be/epmvG3pjpu0?t=5s) when he hears something "appropriate".

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5 4</s> 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 bytes thanks to @Dennis

```
ḣJ
```

Test it at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bijSg&input=&args=IkNvZGVHb2xmIC0gVGhlIEJlc3QgQmFuZyBGb3IgWW91ciBCeXRlIgo)
Or all test cases, also at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bijSgrDh-KCrFk&input=&args=IkNvZGUiLCJuYW1lIiwiaGFyYW1iZSIsInNwIGFjZXM_IiwiMTIzNCIsInNzIgo)

How?

```
ḣJ - Main link takes one argument, e.g. "Code"
 J    - range(length(input)), e.g. [1,2,3,4]
ḣ    - head, x[:y] (implicit vectorization), e.g. "CCoCodCode"
```

Comment: `ḣJ` works too.

Comment: @Dennis heh, forgot about `J ` :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>11</s> 5 bytes

```
:@[fc
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OkBbZmM&input=ImhhcmVtYmUi&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
:@[f           Find all prefixes of the input
    c          Concatenate
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @Luis*

```
t&+Rf)
```

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dCYrUmYp&input=J0NvZGUn)

**Explanation**

```
t       % Implicitly grab the input and duplicate
&+      % Broadcast and create a 2D matrix with all values > 0
R       % Grab the upper triangular portion (sets the lower triangular values to 0)
f       % Get the linear index for each value > 0
)       % Index into the original string (uses modular indexing)
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: Cool Solution! (as MATL answers tend to be)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
.pJ
```

**Explanation**

```
.p   # get list of prefixes of input
  J  # join as string
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LnBK&input=Q29kZQ)

Comment: Damn... I retire

Comment: That .p idea was a goodun

Comment: @JonathanAllan: A prefix command does come in handy now and then yeah :)

Comment: Well.... Shoot.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 13 + 1 = 14 bytes

+1 byte for `-p` flag. Expects input on STDIN. Requires Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`).

```
gsub(/./){$`}
```

See it on eval.in (a few extra bytes since eval.in doesn't support command line flags): 
https://eval.in/637093

Comment: I think this only works with `\r\n` newlines. Otherwise, `.` doesn't have the last character to match (since it doesn't match `\n`).

Comment: @MartinEnder I was actually just wondering *why* this works. That explains it. I forgot eval.in uses `\r\n`. I'll write a version that works with conventional newlines.

Comment: I think assuming `\r\n` newlines is fine since that's the default on Windows (and in your online interpreter apparently). But you should mention it in the answer.

Comment: I was going to post a [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina) answer but it would now be straight port of yours, so if you want to post it yourself, it's simply `.` on the first line and `$\`` on the second.

Comment: @MartinEnder If you want to post it I won't take it personally. It's a pretty obvious solution so I don't feel proprietary about it.

Answer (score 5):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

Recursively appends the shortened strings to the left of the final result:

```
f=s=>s&&f(s.slice(0,-1))+s
```

#### Examples

```js
var
f=s=>s&&f(s.slice(0,-1))+s

console.log(f("Code"));     //  -->   "CCoCodCode"
console.log(f("name"));     //  -->   "nnanamname"
console.log(f("harambe"));  //  -->   "hhaharharaharamharambharambe"
console.log(f("sp aces?")); //  -->   "sspsp sp asp acsp acesp acessp aces?"
console.log(f("1234"));     //  -->   "1121231234"
```

Comment: Smart use of recursion +1

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 25 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/./g,'$`$&')
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>34 29 28</s> 26 bytes

```
reverse=<<scanl(flip(:))[]
```

Comment: I'm just sad I can't use `join.inits` since neither of those are in the Prelude.

Comment: @ballesta25 I know, FeelsBadMan.

Comment: Hmm, `concat.scanl(flip(:))[] $ "Code"` -> `"CoCdoCedoC"`. Each part (1st letter, 1st+2nd letter, ...) is in reverse.

Comment: @nimi is right. It needs to be `reverse=<<scanl(flip(:))[]`

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 10 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the input on STDIN:

```
splode.pl <<< "Hello"
```

`splode.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/./$`/sg
```

This depends on the input being terminated by a newline. This 11 byte version does not need a final newline:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lp
s/.?/$`/g
```

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 8 bytes

Here's 4 separate ways to get 8 bytes

```
l_,),\f<
l{1$\+}*
l{+_}*co
Ll{+_}/;
```

Credits to @MartinEnder for the last one. [Online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l_%2C%29%2C%5Cf%3C&input=aabcde%2001!%40%23).

- `l_,),\f<` creates the range `[0 .. len(s)+1]` then uses `f<` to slice for each number, producing all prefixes.
- `l{1$\+}*` is a fold that duplicates the previous prefix and adds a char to it as it goes.
- `l{+_}*co` is a bit weird - `l{+_}*` is also a fold but it produces the wrong prefixes, skipping the first and doubling the last (e.g. `abcd` -> `ab/abc/abcd/abcd`, slashes for clarity). We then use `c` to turn the last string into just its first character and output it with `o`, to get the first prefix.
- `Ll{+_}/;` is a for-each loop that also duplicates the previous prefix and adds a char to it as it goes. We have an extra copy of the original string once the loop is over, which we pop with `;`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>34</s> 28 bytes

Here's my rough attempt with a recursive solution:

```py
f=lambda s:s and f(s[:-1])+s
```

Ungolfed:

```py
def f(s):
    if s: return f(s[:-1]) + s
    return ''
```

Try it [here](https://ideone.com/dFBTgS)!

Thanks to @Dennis for -6 bytes.

Comment: I got ninja'd by recursives..... 300th time...

Comment: `f=lambda s:s and f(s[:-1])+s` saves 6 bytes.

Comment: Pretty sure you can remove the `f=`

Comment: @OliverNi How would I make the recursive call?

Answer (score 2):

## C, 49 bytes

```c
i;f(char*n){for(i=0;i++<strlen(n);)write(1,n,i);}
```

[Try on Ideone](https://ideone.com/HjgvVU)

Comment: You can golf it down to 41 bytes `i;f(char*v){while(*(v+i))write(1,v,++i);}`

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>91</s> <s>87</s> <s>84</s> 83 bytes

```
void c(string n){var b="";for(int i=0;i<n.Length;)System.Console.Write(b+=n[i++]);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
void c(string n)
{
    var b = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n.Length ; )
    {
        System.Console.Write(b+=n[i++]);
    }
}
```

Thank you Kevin Cruijssen.

Comment: +1 You can golf a few things, though. `string b="";` can be `var b="";` and `i++` can be removed in the for-loop and added to the usage of `i`. So in total it becomes: `void c(string n){var b="";for(int i=0;i<n.Length;){b+=n[i++];System.Console.Write(b);}}`

Comment: Ah, I can finally comment.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I've deleted my previous 84 bytes comment, because apparently it's possible to use `b+=` in the System.out.write.. So [`b=b+n[i++]` can be changed to `b+=n[i++]`](https://ideone.com/fgTMlt) I wasn't sure if `+=` is allowed there, but it is. Guess we both learned some things today. Sorry for making you edit all the time, and welcome to PPCG. :) Also, [Tips for golfing in C#](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) might be interesting to read through.

Comment: Haha yeah.  And for sure, I'll be checking a few tips of the languages I know.

Answer (score 2):

### [Jellyfish](http://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 5 bytes

```
P,\}I
```

[Try it online!](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/#code=UCxcfUk&input=Q29kZQ)

#### Explanation

```
    I  # Read input.
  \}   # Get all prefixes.
 ,     # Flatten.
P      # Print.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 8 bytes

```
òÄ$xhòíî
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w7LDhCR4aMOyw63Drg&input=Y29kZQ)

Answer (score 2):

## sed 41

```
h;:;G;s,.\n,\n,;h;s,\n.*,,;/./b;x;s,\n,,g
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 4 bytes

```
0000000: 8073ec 09                                         .s..
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgIGptcCwgcndkIDEsIGpuegogICAgZndkIDEKICAgIGptcCwgcHV0LCBmd2QgMSwgam56Cmpueg&input=Q29kZQ) Check *Debug* to see the generated SBIN code.

#### Sesos assembly

The binary file above has been generated by assembling the following SASM code.

```lisp
    jmp, rwd 1, jnz
    fwd 1
    jmp, put, fwd 1, jnz
jnz
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>60</s> 49 bytes

Not going to win any golf, but hopefully no shorter R answer is possible

```
cat(substring(s<-readline(),1,1:nchar(s)),sep="")
```

<s>`paste0(substring(s<-readLines(,1),1,1:nchar(s)),collapse="")`</s>

Thanks @MickyT

Comment: Well there's always `cat(substring(s<-readline(),1,1:nchar(s)),sep="")` :)

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 11 bytes

```
q{(L\+:Lo}h
```

Explanation:

```
q                   get input
 {       }h         do while 
  (L                get 1st character and variable L (initialized with "")
    \+              swap and concatenate them
      :Lo           store result in L and print it
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cXsoTFwrOkxvfWg&input=Q29kZQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 3 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
∊,\
```

`∊` flatten the

`,\` cumulative concatenation

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u220A%2C%5C%20%u22C4%20f%A8%27Code%27%20%27name%27%20%27harambe%27%20%27sp%20aces%3F%27%20%271234%27%20%27ss%27&run)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
s._
```

Explanation:

```
s   (s)um together 
 ._ all prefixes
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 47 bytes

Thanks to @deustice

```py
lambda s:''.join(s[:i]for i in range(len(s)+1))
```

[**Ideone it!**](https://ideone.com/jYx2c0)

Comment: You can take out the 0, just `s[:i]` should work

Comment: @deustice Oh, of course, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 24 bytes

Well, I got destroyed by Martin, but here was my solution.

```
1m+`(.*).$
$1$.1$*¶$0
¶
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MW0rYCguKikuJAokMSQuMSQqwrYkMArCtgo&input=Q29kZQ)

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 43 bytes

```
param($n)-join(1..$n.length|%{$n[0..--$_]})
```

Takes input `$n`, loops from `1` to `$n.length`, each iteration slicing `$n` from `0` up to one less than the current number -- done because `.length` is 1-indexed, while array slicing is 0-indexed. Each iteration places characters on the pipeline, those are encapsulated in parens and `-join`ed together into one string. Output is implicit.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\stringsplode-the-string.ps1 'PPCG'
PPPPPCPPCG
```

---

Alternatively, using Jordan's [Ruby submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92536/42963) as a basis, you can get to the following for **22 bytes**

```
$input-replace'.','$`'
```

This feels kinda cheaty, though, since you'd have to explicitly insert a newline into the string that you're piping in, or otherwise do a `Get-Content` or something out of a file that pulls the newlines with it. Valid, but not really common.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 'PPCG
' | .\stringsplode-the-string.ps1 $_
PPPPPCPPCG
```

Comment: If I pipe a string into another program, it gets the `\r\n` at the end automatically. Looks like PowerShell scripts are treated differently in that regard?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yeah. I'm not sure if it's because piping in PowerShell is handled differently than piping in other shells, or because the items passed between the pipe are literal objects and there's no `\r\n` at the end of the literal string. Probably a combination.

Answer (score 1):

## C <s>71</s> 67 Bytes

```
k;f(v){char*m,*n=v;while(*n++)for(k=0,m=v;k<n-v;k++)putchar(*m++);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
FKoh<
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=FKoh%3C&input=Code&warnings=0)

```
      - o = 0
FK    - for i in input:
  oh  -   1+o++
    < -  input[:^]
      - "".join(^)
```

Comment: What does `K` do?

Comment: The `F` automatically pushes each character to the stack, the `K` removes it

Comment: then I suggest you put `FK` on the same line in the explanation

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 16 characters

```
?=@append{s;?}$s
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -n 'sp aces?' | gema '?=@append{s;?}$s'
sspsp sp asp acsp acesp acessp aces?
```

Answer (score 1):

### GNU sed, 30 bytes

```
:;G;h;s/.\n.*//;/./t;g;s/\n//g
```

**Run:**

```sh
echo -n "name" | sed -f stringsplode.sed
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>23</s>  16 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/.?/{$/.prematch}/}  # <-- the Perl 5 entry as a Perl 6 lambda
{[R~] m:ex/^.*/}
{[~] m:ex/^.*?/}
```

## Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
{
  # list reduce using string concatenation operator
  [~]

  # the input implicitly matched against
  m

  # in all possible ways
  :exhaustive

  /
    ^   # must match from the beginning
    .   # any character
    *?  # any number of times non-greedily
  /
}
```

The `m:ex/^.*?/` part produces a list of [Match](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match) values `(｢｣,｢C｣,｢Co｣,｢Cod｣,｢Code｣)`.

The other option `m:ex/^.*/` produces the [Match](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match) values in exactly the opposite order, so they have to be combined in reverse using the `R` meta operator.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 58

```
u=''for s in io.read():gmatch('.')do u=u..s io.write(u)end
```

*Saved 5 Bytes thanks to manatwork*

I love using lua's gmatch and gsub for golfing.

Simply takes io.read(), gmatch's it for any single character, iterating through the entire string.
it assigns the variable st, which slowly builds the entire string as lua iterates, and at every iteration, writes the contents of st.

Comment: Just some general golfing things: you can choose shorter variable name and there is an unnecessary space in front of `end`.

Answer (score 0):

### Go, 90 bytes

```
package main;import."fmt";func main(){s:="";Scan(&s);for i:=0;i<=len(s);i++{Print(s[:i])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## BASH (grep + sed + tr) 36

```
grep -o .|sed ':;p;N;$!b'|tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: `'\n'` → `\\n`.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP , 52 Bytes

```
for(;$i<strlen($t=$argv[1]);)echo substr($t,0,++$i);
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to clean up after previous attempt: variable $l is not used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>39</s> <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
while($c=$argv[1][$i++])echo$s.=$c;
```

works for all examples. String should not countain the `0` character.

## PHP, <s>50</s> <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
while(''<$c=$argv[1][$i++])echo$s.=$c;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket 81 bytes

```
(λ(s)(apply string-append(for/list((i(+ 1(string-length s))))(substring s 0 i))))
```

More readable form:

```
(define(f s)
  (apply
   string-append
   (for/list
       ((i(+ 1(string-length s))))
     (substring s 0 i))))
```

Testing:

```
(f "Code")
"CCoCodCode"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell (lambdabot), 10 bytes

```
join.inits
```

Sample:

```
(join.inits) "Code"
"CCoCodCode"
```

Comment: This doesn't work in standard Haskell, because you need imports for both `join` and `inits` which are added to the byte count. If you have an interpreter/compiler that imports them by default, please specify it as part of the language name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
"GX@:)v!
```

This uses a different approach from [@Suever's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92531/36398).

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkdYQDopdiE&input=J0NvZGUn)

#### Explanation

```
        % Implicit input: string
"       % For each. This repeats as many times as chars in the input string
  G     %   Push input again
  X@    %   Push iteration index, k (varies from 1 to input length)
  :)    %   Get k first chars from input
  v!    %   Concatenate all stack contents horizontally
        % Implicit end
        % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 5 bytes

```
Uå+ q
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=VeUrIHE=&input=IkNvZGUi)

#### How it works

```
       // Implicit: U = input string
Uå+    // Cumulative-reduce the input by addition.
       // This returns an array of all prefixes.
    q  // Join with the empty string.
       // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 74 bytes

```
String h(String a){int l=a.length();return l>1?h(a.substring(0,l-1))+a:a;}
```

or

```
String j(String a){return a.isEmpty()?a:j(a.substring(0,a.length()-1))+a;}
```

Recursive version of Geobits answer.